# custom string format 0,0 with slash or back slash

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

i have a WPF TextBox that user can type number in that . now i am searching for a **string format** that can separate TextBox number each 3 point (like **0,0**) but i want separate text with **Slash** or **Back Slash** or another character. and we do not know how many point our number has.

i am searching for **string format** not Linq solution or etc . i read [Microsoft help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) but cant find any way .

sample = 123456789 == > 123/456/789 (good) --- 123,456,789 (bad)

**Update :**

Thanks guys but i search for some thing like this **stringformat= {}{0:0,0}** etc . i mean dont want use string function like regex , replace or linq or any c# code . i want use a string like {#,#} or etc. see microsoft link in my post i need create a string for my issue.

Comment: hwo about a Regex.Replace which will do that stuff ?

Comment: @meorfi Or just plain old `String.Replace()`?

Comment: as i told i search for string format not other C# Code solution. thanks for help .

Comment: can you provide sample code what is you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the OP insists on the use of `String.Format`:

```
string input; //the input of your textbox
int temp = int.Parse(input); //parse your input into an int

//the Format() adds the decimal points, the replace replaces them with the /
string output = String.Format("{0:0,0}", temp).Replace('.', '/');
```

The important step here is to cast the text of your textbox into an integer, as this simplifies the insertion of the decimal points with `String.Format()`.
Of course, you have to make sure that your textbox is a valid number upon parsing or you may get an exception.

---

**EDIT**

So... you have some *dynamic-length* number and want to format it using a *static* format-string (as regexes, string replaces, ling or any c# code at all (!) are a no go)? This is impossible.
You HAVE TO have some dynamic code creating a format string somewhere.
Without referencing to regexes or string replaces again, here is some code to create a format string depending on your input number.
This way you have just one `String.Format()` call. Perhaps you can put the algorithm to create the format string somewhere else and just call it from whereever you need it.

```
string input; //the input of your textbox
int temp = int.Parse(input); //parse your input into an int

string customString = "{0:";
string tempS = "";

for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    if (i % 3 == 0 && i != 0)
    {
        tempS += "/";
    }

    tempS += "#";
}

tempS = new string(tempS.Reverse().ToArray());

customString += tempS;
customString += "}";

string output = String.Format(customString, temp));
```

Comment: thanks this answer is not that i exact want but better than other :) thx again

Answer (score 2):

You can use [NumberFormatInfo.NumberGroupSeparator Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator.aspx)

Sample from MSDN

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class NumberFormatInfoSample {

    public static void Main() {

    // Gets a NumberFormatInfo associated with the en-US culture.
    NumberFormatInfo nfi = new CultureInfo( "en-US", false ).NumberFormat;

    // Displays a value with the default separator (",").
    Int64 myInt = 123456789;
    Console.WriteLine( myInt.ToString( "N", nfi ) );

    // Displays the same value with a blank as the separator.
    nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";
    Console.WriteLine( myInt.ToString( "N", nfi ) );

    }
}


/* 
This code produces the following output.

123,456,789.00
123 456 789.00
*/
```

for you - set NumberGroupSeparator property to '/'

**UPDATE**
another sample

```
var t = long.Parse("123/456/789",NumberStyles.Any, new NumberFormatInfo() { NumberGroupSeparator = "/" });
var output = string.Format(new NumberFormatInfo() { NumberGroupSeparator="/"}, "{0:0,0}", t);
```

Comment: good solution man but is there any way to do that in string format. because im using telerik reporting too and in telerik textbox i need do that with string format.

Comment: see my update, this is simplest way, because in format string you may say that use group separator, but you can't say which of them.

Comment: thanks for your answer man .i thump up you but best answer is Basti M

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom [`NumberFormatInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Then use it for `ToString` with the ["n"-format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#NFormatString):

```
NumberFormatInfo nfi = (NumberFormatInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.Clone();
nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = "/";
nfi.NumberDecimalDigits = 0;   // otherwise the "n" format specifier adds .00
Console.Write(123456789.ToString("n", nfi));  // 123/456/789
```

Comment: good solution man but is there any way to do that in string format. because im using telerik reporting too and in telerik textbox i need do that with string format.