# Decimal numbers are turning into incorrect fractions in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am inputing this:

```
List<double> weightItems = new List<double> {0.23, 0.18, 0.18, 0.27, 0.14};
```

And when I output it like this:

```
objStr += "Weights: [" + String.Join(",", weightItems) + "]\n";
return objStr;
```

And I am getting this as an output:
Weights: [0/23,0/18,0/18,0/27,0/14]

Not sure why I am getting this. Thank you for any help

Comment: The code posted before the edit will not compile. The code posted after the edit returns this result: Weights: [0.23,0.18,0.18,0.27,0.14].

Comment: Looks fine to me. I see the correct results in the outputted string.

Comment: You might want to check what is the actual value of  `NumberFormatInfo.NumberGroupSeparator` in runtime.
Also, this question looks related
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19631640/custom-string-format-0-0-with-slash-or-back-slash/19631819#19631819

Comment: I need to use the weights list and make calculations using them. How do I find out if the calculations are done with 0.23 and not 0/23?

Comment: Could because the current thread's culture uses a "momayyez" as decimal separator, which might be displayed as a slash. Especially in Persian culture (at least that's what they say here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49807906/why-does-nko-use-3-decimal-places-for-displaying-fixed-point-f-numbers-whil

Answer (score 1):

First of all, lets modify this code a bit for it to compile:

```
   List<double> weightItems = new List<double> { 0.23, 0.18, 0.18, 0.27, 0.14 };
        var objStr = "Weights: [" + String.Join(",", weightItems) + "]\n";
        Console.WriteLine(objStr);
```

This should return the following:

> Weights: [0.23,0.18,0.18,0.27,0.14]

if this doesn't work, it is probably because you have your CultureInfo set wrong.

To fix this issue, you should include this line before you using String.Join()

```
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");
```

if you want to replecate this issue - include the same line with `"fa-Ir"` instead

```
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fa-Ir");
```

Which will change your results to the following:

> Weights: [0/23,0/18,0/18,0/27,0/14]

[lidqy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5739443/lidqy) posted a relevant link in the comments

[lidqy's link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49807906/why-does-nko-use-3-decimal-places-for-displaying-fixed-point-f-numbers-whil)

Answer (score 0):

If you're afraid that the values are corrupted, you can easily display the values with '.' as decimal point by specifiying for example InvariantCulture (or any other culture that uses a '.' decimal separator).

```
//1. Specifying culture in explicit string format
List<double> weightItems = new List<double> { 0.23, 0.18, 0.18, 0.27, 0.14 };
var str = "Weights: [" + string.Join(",", weightItems.Select(d => d.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))) + "]\n";
Console.WriteLine(str);

//2. Specifying thread culture and using it in implicit string format
List<double> weightItems = new List<double> { 0.23, 0.18, 0.18, 0.27, 0.14 };
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
var str = "Weights: [" + string.Join(",", weightItems) + "]\n";    
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Both outputs: `"Weights: [0.23,0.18,0.18,0.27,0.14]"`